# i want show different images continuously without user touch the button

Tags: ios, objective-c

when the user touch the button the below code show the image.i want show different images like "bear,cat,cow,dog" continuously without user touch the button.can any one help me.

```
NSMutableArray *dashBoy = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (i = 1; i<= 12; i++)
 {
    butterfly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear_%d.png", i]; 
    if ((image = [UIImage imageNamed:butterfly]))
        [dashBoy addObject:image]; 
} 
[stgImageView setAnimationImages:dashBoy]; 
[stgImageView setAnimationDuration:4.0f];
[stgImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
[stgImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: You need to show that you've made some effort to solve this problem. What research have you done?

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment, it's hard to read. Edit your question to include the code, and the explanation of what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below:-

Firstly, create a UIImageView property like below,

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;    //Also connect it with storyboard or xib.
```

Then you could write down IBAction as follow:-

```
- (IBAction)startTap:(id)sender {
[self.imageView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];    //You could change the duration for making animation fast or slow.
[self.imageView setAnimationImages:imageArray];   //imageArray is NSArray of images of which you want to show slide show.
[self.imageView startAnimating];    //simply to start animation.
}

- (IBAction)stopTap:(id)sender {
[self.imageView stopAnimating];    //To stop animation.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this..
create two instance objects like

`NSMutableArray * imagesArray;` and `UIImageView *animationImageView;`

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSArray *imageNames = @[@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png", @"img4.png",@"img5.png"];
        imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) 
            {
                [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
            animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
            animationImageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
            animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5; // set your own
            [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
     }
```

and to start and stop two `UIButton` Actions

```
-(IBAction)startAnimation:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
}
-(IBAction)stopAnimation:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [animationImageView stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: why down vote can you give me the reason @ down voter